# Leetcode compiler throws error on lines 29 and 39 despite code having only 5 lines

Tags: python, compiler-errors

Started Leetcode today, First problem was to add two numbers (ik, very easy but still, link: https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-integers/).

My answer is of five lines but the compiler says it has detected two errors on line 29 and 39

My answer:

```
num1 = 12
num2 = 5
sum = num1 + num2

print(sum)
```

Compiler error:

```
NameError: global name 'Solution' is not defined
    ret = Solution().sum(param_1, param_2)
Line 29 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 39 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Which makes absolutely no sense as there is no such line in my code

I have tried reloading, closing tab, etc. but to no effect. What am I doing wrong?

[This photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RL3E.png) contains the screenshot of the problem and my solution along with compile errors.

Comment: where is your `class` and `def`? try this : ```class Solution:
    def sum(self, num1: int, num2: int) -> int:
        return num1 + num2```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the function signature (see below):

```py
class Solution:
    def sum(self, num1: int, num2: int) -> int:
```

Hence, your solution would be

```py
class Solution:
    def sum(self, num1: int, num2: int) -> int:
        sum = num1 + num2
        return sum
```

This is because LeetCode runs your code within its judging system, and has testing code which you can't see (which is why it errors out at line 29 and 39).